# Output interim results in new window during tkinter mainloop - Threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm working on a GUI for a math application. Since the calculations often take some time, I'd like to output the interim results to a textfield in a new tkinter window which shall open when the calculation is initiated.

I got to the point where I was able to open a new window and conduct the calculation, but the results are printed after the calculation ends.

I prepared a short code snippet which shows my approach:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time as t

class CalculationDialog(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.textField = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.bCloseDialog = tk.Button(self.root, text="Close", state=tk.DISABLED, command=self.root.destroy)
        self.textField.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.bCloseDialog.grid(row=2, column=0)

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):

        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)

        self.root.mainloop()


def calculate():
    app = CalculationDialog()

    # Conduct calculation and output to textfield of app

    func(app.textField,0)

def func(output,input):
    for i in range(input,100):
        result = i**2
        output.insert(tk.END,str(result)+"\n")
        t.sleep(0.1)



main = tk.Tk()

buttonCalc = tk.Button(main,text="Calculate",command=calculate)
buttonCalc.pack(side=tk.TOP)

main.mainloop()
```

Does anyone have a suggestion what I am missing?
I sometimes get an error saying that `CalculationDialog` has no attribute `root`.
This error is not always raised however.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @HenryYik answer, which shows the correct approach but throws a `RuntimeError`when attempting to click `calculate` several times in a row:

`RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`

The following example pops a `tk.Toplevel` that shows the intermediate results, and allows clicking repeatedly the `calculate` button. It will spawn as many toplevel windows, showing as many intermediate results.
Each new thread is identified by a unique number; a console output is printed when a thread is done.

The `close` button on the `Toplevel` becomes active when the calculation finishes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time


def func(thread_number=[0]):   # note: the mutable default arg creates a closure that keeps track of the thread number.
    global thr
    local_thread_number = thread_number[0]
    thread_number[0] += 1
    def close():
        thr = None
        top.destroy()
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    text_field = tk.Text(top)
    close_btn = tk.Button(top, text="Close", state=tk.DISABLED, command=close)
    text_field.grid(row=1, column=0)
    close_btn.grid(row=2, column=0)
    for i in range(1, 100):
        result = i**2
        if i % 10 == 0:
            text_field.insert(tk.END, str(result)+"\n")
        time.sleep(0.05)
    print(f'thread {local_thread_number} done!')
    close_btn.config(state=tk.NORMAL)


def get_and_start_thread():
    global thr
    thr = threading.Thread(target=func)
    thr.start()


root = tk.Tk()
thr = None

button_calc = tk.Button(root,text="Calculate",command=get_and_start_thread)
button_calc.pack(side=tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ... I unfortuanetly was sick. This helped a lot, thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help; I hope you are feeling better now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to thread the function that does the calculation, which is `func`. Right now you are threading the creation of another Tk instance and some widgets.

It can be something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time as t

def func():
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    textField = tk.Text(frame)
    bCloseDialog = tk.Button(frame, text="Close", state=tk.DISABLED, command=root.destroy)
    textField.grid(row=1, column=0)
    bCloseDialog.grid(row=2, column=0)
    for i in range(1,100):
        result = i**2
        textField.insert(tk.END,str(result)+"\n")
        t.sleep(0.1)

root = tk.Tk()
thr = threading.Thread(target=func)

buttonCalc = tk.Button(root,text="Calculate",command=thr.start)
buttonCalc.pack(side=tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: upvoted for the correct approach, but your program has bugs. It  notably throws a `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once` when `calculate` is clicked several times.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I was thinking on the perspective that I usually limit users from spamming the same button/functions over and over - but if is allowed, then yes OP should use your approach instead.

Comment: Yes, agreed @HenryYik, restricting the number of clicks, is a valid approach too.